# How to use non-breaking space in code-span of Markup-Cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-dyalog-kernel

I am writing my first notebook and am discussing some code in it. So I have a markdown-cell for the text and am quoting a statement inside ``. Would like to the code of that statement to be shown w/o linebreaks, so I tried injecting `nbsp;`-statements, but when the markdown-cell is executed, the `&nbsp`is shown verbatim (so I get `some&nbsp;code`). Is there a way to prevent this?

(BTW: the notebook uses the new kernel for [Dyalog APL](https://github.com/Dyalog/dyalog-jupyter-kernel), but AFAIK choice of kernel should not affect formatting of markdown, so this probably is a general issue)

**Update**: a coworker suggested to use the non-breaking space directly (U+00A0), so I pasted that (" ") into the browser-UI of Jupyter without success. I edited the `.ipynb`-file directly and pasted it at the desired position, but it did not affect layout (line wrapped at that position regardless).